# Is there a way to programmatically access the "out of office" status area in Teams group chat views?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Teams appears to have a feature to display miscellaneous messaging in group chat views, just above the conversation message box.  I have noticed this when unable to connect to a chat thread, as well as when a member of the group is out of the office and may not respond.

[image: Screen capture of group chat with area in question outlined in red]

Is is possible to access this programmatically and add our own messages?  We're hoping to add retention information for given chat threads and this would be the perfect location to do so.  Unfortunately, I've been unable to locate information on this in the SDK docs or elsewhere online.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not supported. Could you please Raise a [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)?